# Compiling ocaml with module Llvm_analysis

Tags: compilation, functional-programming, compiler-construction, ocaml, llvm

I'm working through chapter 3 of the tutorial of LLVM, 
The given file myocamlbuild.ml is:

```
open Ocamlbuild_plugin;;

ocaml_lib ~extern:true "llvm";;
ocaml_lib ~extern:true "llvm_analysis";;

flag ["link"; "ocaml"; "g++"] (S[A"-cc"; A"g++"]);;
```

But I find if I run

```
ocamlbuild -pkg llvm repl.byte
```

Error message is: the required module llvm_analysis is unavailable.
What did I do wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: also, feel free to join our OCaml discord chat, sometimes it is much faster to get answers there https://discord.gg/MaJWj2j
(or even drop by my office CIC 2205)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've followed some outdated and probably wrong instructions. If you will install llvm from opam, it will be correctly packaged, and in order to use the `llvm_analysis` library, you just need to use `-pkg llvm.analysis` option of the ocamlbuild tool.

So, erase `myocamlbuild.ml` file, and any other support files, that you've created (e.g., `_tags`), and compile it as follows

```
 ocamlbuild -pkgs llvm,llvm.analysis repl.byte
```

or

```
 ocamlbuild -pkgs llvm,llvm.analysis repl.native
```

Add other llvm subpackages after the comma (no whitespaces).

To get the list of all llvm subpackages use the following command:

```
 ocamlfind list | grep llvm
```

See also my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50631727/2625442) to your previous questions for the detailed description on how to setup a new project, that uses llvm